# My Jeep is making a squeaky noise when I apply the brakes and when I drive slowly it makes a clunking noise

Tags: brakes, jeep, grand-cherokee

I have a 2002 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo. I just bought it two weeks ago so I don't know much about it. They guy I got it off of said it has brand new brakes, rotors, and calipers.

When I apply the brakes it makes a squeaky noise and sounds like it is only coming from the front drivers side. On that same side when I drive slowly, it makes a clicking/clunking noise. Does anyone know what this could be considering it has brand new brakes, rotors, and calipers?

Also, when I apply the brakes it doesn't feel like it is stopping as fast as it should, but like I said I just got it two weeks ago so I'm not really familiar how the Grand Cherokee works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Going only from the information here, I'd say there were two issues going on.

Firstly, I'd say that the brake job was done incorrectly/badly. A squeaky noise when you apply the brakes is often because the mechanic didn't put any copperslip or similar hi temperature grease on the back of the brake pads (not the bit touching the caliper!). The 'not stopping as fast as it should' could also be related, if the brake system was not bled correctly - if there is air in the brake lines, you're not going to stop quickly, because you need to compress the air before the hydraulic fluid can do anything on the pads.

For the clicking/clunking; does it get worse when you turn corners? Find a car park, and drive around in circles. If it gets worse when you're turning to the right, it's the left-hand side CV joint; if worse when you're turning to the left, it's the right-hand side CV joint. In either case, the cheapest/best/quickest solution is to replace the driveshaft on the affected side (or both sides if you wish - they're pretty cheap, and the one that hasn't gone yet is the same age as the one that *has* gone)

For a quick confirmation of this, take the car to a reputable garage and ask them to check it out. May cost you 30 minutes of their time, but if you give them the job to fix it, the diagnosis should be free. All of these issues are doable by someone with a few basic tools, but a garage should set your mind at rest. Do NOT take the car back to whoever did the original brake job!